# Can I create an Azure AD registered multi-tenant application that can access OneDrive for Business data on both cloud only tenants and on-prem farms?

Tags: azure, sharepoint-2013, office365, onedrive

I'm creating a multi-tenant application on Azure AD that needs access to OneDrive for Business for both cloud tenants and on-prem farms. Here is my scenario:

- My application makes REST calls using the SharePoint 2013 REST API.
- The scenario or class of the app is "[Daemon/Server Application to Web API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api)".
- My app needs needs app-only permissions since the application runs at a scheduled time without user interaction.
- Based on the class of app I'm building and the permissions I need, I'm using the `Client Credentials Oauth 2.0` flow to allow app-only authentication. The admin running my app gives consent for the tenant once for the app, and then the app is allowed to run on it's own thereafter.

Everything works fine for accessing data on the cloud-only tenants, but I'm not sure if it's possible to also access data for on-prem farms that don't have a tenancy in Azure AD.

Note, I was able to make a SharePoint app that was able to access both, but SharePoint apps don't allow for apps with app-only permissions that grant full-control to a tenant on the fly, so I have to go the Azure AD application route because full control can be granted to apps on the fly.